# Play! JPA: Enforce not to create Entity on load

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I am connecting to an external database (i.e. Oracle 10g) using my Play 1.2.4 application.

I have provided all the DB details in the application.conf file, then added the ojdbc.jar in the classpath and the connection seems to work fine. But the problem is everytime when the application access some data for the first time. it is trying to create the entity table (which is already present) and hence throws an exception.

I don't want to create any table since its already there with some data, hence how can I avoid this?

There might be some configuration to set in the application.conf for accessing the external database where the table is already available(I believe), kindly help me on this.

Below is the **conf** file:

```
application.mode=dev
%prod.application.mode=prod

 db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
 db.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
 db.user=****
 db.pass=****

#%test.module.cobertura=${play.path}/modules/cobertura
%test.application.mode=dev
%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
%test.jpa.ddl=create
%test.mail.smtp=mock
```

**Note**: Presently I am connecting to the external Oracle database and not with the embedded H2 database.

Comment: Can you post your .conf ? Note that in DEV mode, Play tries to create table, but not in PROD mode, if I remember well.

Comment: I have added the conf entries in the above post. The remaining entries are commented out (`#`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application.conf set the following property to none:

**jpa.ddl=none**

Comment: +1 for the reply... Will check that out once in a while and then will close off this thread :)